# Opening specific links in MobileSafari from iOS phonegap app

Tags: ios, cordova

I'm developing an application for iPad, which is coded using Phonegap 1.7. Working with iframes is needed, so I enable the domains I want to access to in the white list and set OpenAllWhitelistURLsInWebView to YES on the Cordova.plist. The problem is that I'd like to open some specific links in a MobileSafari browser, not in the webview. According to the [Phonegap wiki](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/51586852/iFrames%20and%20PhoneGap):

> Enabling iFrames on PhoneGap-iOS requires that you whitelist the
>   iframe domains and enable "OpenAllWhitelistURLsInWebView". While this
>   doesn't sound like a problem, many applications want to open specific
>   sites in MobileSafari (not a ChildBrowser), which cannot be
>   accomplished easily when "OpenAllWhitelistURLsInWebView" is enabled.

So, although that "cannot be accomplished easily", is there any way to accomplish it?